# Someway to listen for new elements without using .on()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple hover function that adds a close button to an LI. The problem is, new LI's are created and the hover no longer works. I know the `.On();` will watch for newly created elements but that seems to only work with `.click()`.

JS :

```
 $("#sortable li").hover(function () {
     $(this).find(".close").show();
 },
 function () {
     $(this).find(".close").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegated form of event handling, but it doesn't work with the pseudo event `hover` so you need to watch both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
$("#sortable").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    // mouse over code here
    $(this).find(".close").show();
});

$("#sortable").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    // write your hover out code here
    $(this).find(".close").hide();
});
```

or a more compact form:

```
$("#sortable").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // mouse over code here
        $(this).find(".close").show();
    }, 
    mouseleave: function() {
        // mouse leave code here
        $(this).find(".close").hide();
    }
 }, "li");
```

The way this works is that mouse events bubble up the part chain so this delegated form of `.on()` watches the `#sortable` parent for events that originated on child `li` tags and then triggers your callback when they match the desired event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sortable').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).find(".close").show();
        },
    mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).find(".close").hide();
        }
}, 'li');
```